# Scrape href attribute from a youtube playlist using HTML Aligity pack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to scrape a href from a youtubelplaylist-link using HTML agility pack.
This code works, but the problem is that it's a table, and I don't know how to scrape each href separately.

```
            var html = new HtmlDocument();
        html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC"));
        var root = html.DocumentNode;
        var p = root.Descendants()
            .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("pl-video-title"))
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Descendants("a").Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href", ""))
            .FirstOrDefault();

            var points = ("https://youtube.com/embed/" + (Regex.Replace(p, "list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC&index=1", "").Trim()));
```

This code works, but the problem is that it's a table and with this code I only recieve the first href, and I don't know how to scrape each href separately in the table (about 10 of them). This is the "Selector/ID/class" I wan't to scrape from:

```
#pl-load-more-destination > tr:nth-child(1) > td.pl-video-title
```

When I put this in instead of "pl-video-title" I get error.

I've been looking at XPath but I can't get it to work..

Comment: Should take a look here as its picking every link http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the href of the playlist links/videos, you can get them with the following:

(Note that I use `ScrapySharp nuget` library along with `HtmlAgilityPack` to provide support for css selectors, using CssSelect extension (adding `using ScrapySharp.Extensions`)

```
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = w.Load("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC");
```

The output looks like

`/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0&amp;list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC&amp;index=1`
where the index parameter changes according to the number of link in the list.

Don't forget to add www.youtube.com to the link if you plan to use it in a further scraping (like it is it is not a valid uri to access from outside the site since it is not absolute).

```
var links = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".pl-video-title-link");
foreach (var link in links)
    Console.WriteLine(link.GetAttributeValue("href"));
```

**Update:**

To remove a given key from the url query string, here's a simple way to do it:

```
    string url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbEoRnaOIbs&list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC&index=100";

    var parsedQs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url);
    parsedQs.Remove("index");

    Console.WriteLine(parsedQs.ToString());
```

The url will then look like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the code and recieved: 

`/watch?v=bbEoRnaOIbs&list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC&index=100`



(The the hundredth in the table)
Is there a way to get a specific one? Let's say the fourth one.

Comment: `links` is a an `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>` object, meaning you have all `System.Linq` extension methods at your service. To get a specific one (the 4th like you ask), `links.ElementAt(3)` will do it.

Comment: Alright, thank you! That worked. Last question: How do I get rid "&index=X"?

Comment: What do you mean by `get rid of &index=X` ? the `index` variable in the `query string` is necessary to determine the specific result page you want to reference.

Comment: Okey, nevermind. The url still lead to the youtube video so it doesn't matter. Thank you very much for your help sir!

Comment: I updated the answer with what you asked. Would you mind marking it as an answer, if it provided what you were looking for ?